# Showing that a function with a second-order zero at $m$ is sent to zero by the whole $T_mM$.

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I was given the following as an exercise.

> Prove that if $f\in\mathcal{C}^\infty(M)$ where $M$ is a manifold, $f(m)=0$ for some $m\in M$, and the zero is second-order, i.e. in some chart $\phi$ we have $f\circ\phi^{-1}$ with derivatives all zero, then all $v\in T_mM$ send $f$ to 0, i.e. $v(f)=0$ for all $v\in T_mM$.

$T_mM$ was defined as the space of all tangent vectors, which were defined as follows.

> $v:\mathcal{C}^\infty(M)\to\mathbb R$ is a tangent vector at $m\in M$ if:

1. It is linear, i.e. $v(\alpha f+\beta g)=\alpha v(f)+\beta v(g)$ for all $f,g\in\mathcal{C}^\infty(M)$;
2. It satisfies the Leibniz rule, that is $v(fg)=f(m)v(g)+g(m)v(f)$ for all $f,g\in\mathcal{C}^\infty(M)$.

In another course, tangent vectors were defined as linear functionals on germs satisfying Leibniz. So the domain of $v$ were not $\mathcal{C}^\infty(M)$, but a quotient of that, identifying all functions coinciding in a neighborhood of $m$.

Unfortunately, no mention of germs was made in the definition of this course, so a priori I cannot say that if $f=g$ in a neighborhood of $m$, then $v(f)=v(g)$ for any $v\in T_mM$.

My try would have been to use the well-known basis of $T_mM$, the derivative vectors. However:

1. The exercise was given *before* proving those vectors are a basis, so it should be possible to do it without them;
2. The exercise was *used to prove* those vectors are a basis, so it must be possible without them.

Here is how the statement about derivative vectors was proved.

- Consider $D$ a derivation at $m$ acting on $\mathcal{C}^\infty(M)$. Then it induces a derivation at $m$ acting on $\mathcal{C}^\infty(U)$, where $U$ is any open set in $M$. That is because I can take $f\in\mathcal{C}^\infty(U)$ and extend it. This extension is done via a bump function $\rho\in\mathcal{C}^\infty(M)$ which is one in a neighborhood of $m$, zero outside $U$, and smooth all over $M$. We define $\hat D(f)$ to be $D(\rho f)$. As long as we choose $\rho$ as said above, the $\hat D$ will not depend on $\rho$, since any two extensions $\rho_1f,\rho_2f$ will coincide in a neighborhood of $m$, precisely where both $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ are equal to 1. If two functions coincide in a neighborhood of $m$, their difference has a second-order zero at $m$, hence, by the exercise, $D(\rho_1f-\rho_2f)=0$.
- If I choose $U$ to be the domain of a local chart $\phi$, I can expand $f\circ\phi^{-1}$ with a sort of Taylor expansion, then deduce a similar expansion for $f$, and finally deduce from that expansion that I can reconstruct any derivation at $m$ acting on $\mathcal{C}^\infty(U)$ via the particular derivations that map a function $f\in\mathcal{C}^\infty(U)$ to one of the derivatives of $f\circ\phi^{-1}$ at $\phi(m)$.
- But then any derivative acting on $\mathcal{C}^\infty(M)$ induces one on $\mathcal{C}^\infty(U)$, so I have a system of generators for $T_mM$.
- And oh well those generators are independent and thus a basis.

So I cannot (AFAICS) go local in my exercise, because that would require inducing a tangent vector to $U$ from $v\in T_mM$, and that should be done by some extension of $f$ to $M$, and that would require well-posedness of the image of the extension, which, as seen above, was proved with the second-order thing, since clearly any two extensions of $f$ to $M$ coincide in the neighborhood $U$ of $m$. So how can I solve this problem?

How can I prove either of the following two?

- The properties given for tangent vectors imply locality, i.e. that if $f=g$ in a neighborhood of $m$ then $v(f)=v(g)$ for all $v\in T_mM$.
- The stronger second-order statement at the question start.

Comment: This is very wordy. Am I correct in understanding that you are *given* that all first-order derivatives of $f\circ\phi^{-1}$ vanish at $\phi(m)$ and you're trying to *prove* that every derivation at $m$ kills $f$? Have you not proved that $\partial/\partial x^i$ (working in the chart $\phi$) give a basis for $T_mM$? ... I cannot understand where all this stuff with germs came from, since your derivations are defined on all of $C^\infty(M)$.

Comment: The way we proved it wad a basis uses this second-order zero statement I'm trying to prove @Ted. It first notes that, given $D$ a derivation on $M$, it induces a derivation $\hat D$ on an open set $U\subseteq M$, by taking a function $f$ on $U$, extending it to $M$ via a bump function $\rho$, and defining $\hat D(f):=D(\rho\cdot f)$, $\rho\cdot f$ being defined as zero outside $U$. It proves the definition is independent of the choice of $\rho$ by notig any twu such extensions will.coincide in a neighborhood of the point $D$ is deriving at, and hence the difference is a second-order zero...

Comment: ...and any derivation gives zero on it. Then it chooses $U$ as the domain of a chart in order to have those particular derivations. So what I really need to prove is that, given a derivation $D$ at a point $m$, if $f=g$ in a neighborhood of $m$, then $Df=Dg$, or in other words that $D$ induces a well-defined function on germs.

Comment: Is the problem clearer now @Ted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so the issue is to prove that a derivation at the point $m$ depends only on the values of the function on (any) neighborhood of $m$. It suffices to prove that if $f$ is $0$ on a neighborhood $U$ of $m$, then $v(f)=0$. Take a smooth function $\rho$ supported in $U$ with $\rho(m)=1$. Then $\rho f$ is a smooth function on all of $M$ and $\rho f = 0$ everywhere. Therefore,
$$0=v(\rho f) = v(\rho)f(m) + \rho(m)v(f) = 0 + v(f),$$
so $v(f)=0$, as needed.